# install maven archetype project jar with *.pom file to local repo

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

i`m kinda new to maven and want to know how to install an archetype jar to my local repo

i got a directory com.foo with the following files:

```
maven_metadata_local.xml
[1.00.00-SNAPSHOT]
```

which containes these files

```
_maven.repository
   foo-archetype-1.00.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
   foo-archetype-1.00.00-SNAPSHOT.pom
   maven_metadata_local.xml
```

from what i read i understand that there is a way to build a template project using this archetype but first i need to install it to my local repo
how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i managed to do that:

what i did is opened the `maven_metadata_local.xml` to get the groupId, artifactId, and version

run this command from that directory

```
mvn install:install-file                            
-Dfile=foo-archetype-1.00.00-SNAPSHOT.jar     \
-DgroupId=com.foo                             \
-DartifactId=foo-archetype                    \
-Dversion=1.00.00-SNAPSHOT                    \
-Dpackaging=jar                               \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

once compleated (`BUILD SUCCESS`) i got the build in my local repository
go to a folder from which i want to create a project
run this command

```
mvn archetype:generate                \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.foo            \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=foo-archetype   \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.00.00-SNAPSHOT   \
-DgroupId=com.mycom                   \
-DartifactId=myApp                    \
-Dversion=myversion-SNAPSHOT
```

in eclipse i imported an existing maven project, right click on the project->maven->update
and i got the full build ready to work

Answer (score 1):

Adding an archetype to your local repository is no different than adding any other dependency.  You can simply run a `mvn install` command on it.

Comment: this is what i did but i got this error
`The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory`

Comment: i followed this example http://jeff.langcode.com/archives/27 and at there is a new directory with 3 files like before but the archetype is still not in my local repository

Comment: Use `cmd`, Go to where has file `pom.xml`, then type `mvn install`