# How to create a war file using terminal

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, terminal, pom.xml

I need to to know how to create a war file using "terminal" application in Ubuntu system.what commands should be executed and what steps should be followed after defining the path/target folder

here is my POM file content

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.erp</groupId>
    <artifactId>erp-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>erp-web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Backend API project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.erp</groupId>
            <artifactId>erp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mycode</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

*When I ran Maven command(mvn clean install) im getting this error*

```
Missing:
----------
1) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Comment: Can you post some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried running Maven command (mvn clean install) then Im getting an error. its complaining about missing dependency files.(1) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT)

Answer (score 0):

Under the project path, `$ jar -cvf YOUR_WAR.war *` should do the stuff (after file compilation with the `javac` command) where you can replace the asterisc with custom file targets separated with a comma `,`.

However I highly recommand using a **build/packaging** tool such as Apache Maven or Ant.
With maven you can use [mave-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to generate a web archive and for Apache Ant you can follow this [war build sample](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/ant/ant-sample-build-file-war-1.html).

BR.

Comment: I have the project. but the thing is I cant run Maven command. its complaining about missing file.(1) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Seems a missing dependency issue, could you post your pom.xml file please and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi I have copy paste my POM files content. Please take a look

Comment: I tried to download missing dependency but it failed. its giving me above error

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit worried about the below dependency since all others seems familiar ones:
 com.erp erp 1.0-SNAPSHOT  
So is this a cutom project your developed yourself?
Then you should install this archetype into local repository.

Comment: This project was done by someone else. Unfortunately I don't have any contact with him. Can you please explain me how to do that?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I Tried this command (mvn install:install-file). but its giving me build error. Am I missing something here..?

I followed the instruction in below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406652/install-maven-archetype-project-jar-with-pom-file-to-local-repo

Comment: Do you have the sources of the **com.erp** project? Or even the packaged archive (.jar file)?

Comment: So you have to install it into your local repository: Use the `$ mvn clean install` command inside the project (com.erp) root folder.
You should see a message like *[INFO] Installing erp.jar to 
$LOCAL_REPO/com/erp/erp.jar*.

Comment: Hi tmarwen. what do you mean by root folder.. Our project was in desktop. after we go to project folder it has SRC, TARGET, folders and POM.xml file. so what was we doing, we change the path to 'cd Desktop/project' and we ran this maven command (mvn clean install) so then only we are getting above error about missing dependency. Is our path correct? do we need to go inside either 'SRC' or 'target' folder

Comment: Your path is totally correct, but as mentionned before you need to install the dependency **erp** then your project project. So use the `mvn clean install` in the root folder of the erp project not yours.

Comment: I am really sorry for asking so many questions but,i really don't understand this step. Can you please explain this further with an example??

Thanks :)

Comment: No need to excuse, it is as simple as that your project depends on some artifact A (erp.jar) and since this dependency is not available in a remote managed repository so maven won't find it when trying to download it then it will look into local repository. So unless you install it, maven agent won't find it at all and your build will fail. That's why you need to install it locally (or deployed on some proxied mirror but this will be an advanced topic).